# How to delete rows in SQL that contain duplicate values in just one column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data in a table:

| id | name | symbol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Two | Three |
| 2 | Two | Three |
| 3 | Three | Three |
| 4 | Three | Three |
| 5 | Three | Three |

and want to delete all rows such as the column `name` only contains unique values. It doesn't matter which rows gets deleted in case of duplicate values in column `name`.

So desired output would be e.g.

| id | name | symbol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Two | Three |
| 3 | Three | Three |

I have a postgres td and this is what I tried based on a tutorial:

```
;with cte as
(
    select
        *,
        row_num = row_number() over (partition by name order by ID)
    from public.tentacle_ticker
)
delete
from cte
where row_num > 1;
```

which returns `column "row_num" does not exist`

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: `row_num = <expr>` is a syntax extension of SQL Server. In PostgreSQL you can use the SQL Standard form `<expr> as row_num`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you require.  An expanded comment more than an answer

```
   delete from table
    where
    id not in
    (
    select min(id)
    from
    table 
    group by name,symbol
    )
```